# Why do my Xcode simulator and Android emulator constantly refresh sometimes?

Tags: refresh, xcode14, android-studio-electric-eel

I've been developing the same React Native app for about a year and recently I've noticed that on both iOS simulators, Android emulators, and physical devices, sometimes that little pop up that says "Refreshing" (that comes up when you actually make a change and save) constantly appears, even if I haven't changed anything.

It only happens sometimes and I can usually navigate normally throughout my app (though sometimes it crashes when this is happening, not sure it's related). Sometimes it just randomly stops though. It's very annoying at best and at worst I fear something is not right.

Since it happens on both iOS and Android, I feel like it must be something with React Native? I don't see anything in the logs about it and I haven't been able to find any issues whose solutions fixed things but here are the things I've tried:

- Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches...
- Cleaning the build folders in XCode and Android Studio
- Updating to latest versions (XCode 14.2 and Android Studio Electric Eel)
- Restarting Xcode, Android Studio, and my computer
- Increasing the Internal and SD Card storage to 1024 MB on an emulator. I'm unable to change the RAM or VM Heap.

Using React Native 0.67.4 and Ventura 13.1 on an M1 MacAir. It also happens on Monterrey 12.6.2 on an Intel Mac.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen? Thanks in advance!